ODBC Firebird connections limit
I have simple code that creates connection to Firebird (any version, from 2.5 to 5.0).
C#, x64, FbConnection, 1000 connections, all working fine:
List<FbConnection> fbList = new List<FbConnection>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    try
    {

        var connection = new FbConnection("User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=localhost/3053:c:\\rollcontrol\\rollcontrol;Pooling=false; MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=2000");
        connection.Open();

        fbList.Add(connection);
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + e.ToString());
    }
}

C#, x64, OdbcConnection, 1000 connections, process stopping on 180 connections (no error, the process just hangs):
List<OdbcConnection> odbcList = new List<OdbcConnection>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    try {

        OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=rollcontrol");
        DbConnection.Open();

        odbcList.Add(DbConnection);
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + e.ToString());
    }
}

ODBC has a limit on the number of connections? Maybe, it is possible to increase the limit number of connections?
UPDATE
Issue fixed in Firebird ODBC Driver 3.0.16 and ODBC 2.0.6

Which Firebird ODBC driver are you using, and what version?

I tested everything possible: Firebird 2.5.9 + ODBC 2.0, Firebird 2.5.9 + ODBC 3.0, Firebird 3.0 + ODBC 2.0, Firebird 3.0 + ODBC 3.0, Firebird 4/5 + ODBC 2.0/3.0

More info I posted to Firebird ODBC github: https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird-odbc-driver/issues/236 Now I rollback to Firebird 2.0 + ODBC 2.0, it is more stable for me

As hashed out in the issue your reported, this is a bug in the Firebird ODBC driver that only happens with connections created by administrators (SYSDBA and users specifying the RDB$ADMIN role).
The driver tries to find out the current real user of the connection by requesting isc_info_user_names, which for administrators reports the usernames for all connections to the current database in the current server process, and not just the username for the current connection, which with a lot of connections causes a truncation, which the driver doesn't (or since your pull request, didn't) handle correctly.
As a workaround, you can do one of the following:

Use a non-administrator user

Use Firebird ClassicServer (specify ServerMode = Classic in firebird.conf).
In ClassicServer mode, each connection has its own process, so the isc_info_user_names information request only reports one user, even for administrators.


